"残ったとばれない程度に" what does it mean here?
"日向は？"
"経費申請少しやっちゃいます。残ったとばれない程度に"
The character is leaving the office. So he asks his colleague what he'll do.
The colleague replied with this. I understand 経費申請 is "I'll submit a cost application" but what does 残ったとばれない mean here? To degree that it won't?

You said this is a conversation just before leaving the office, and that's the most important clue. This 残る likely means to stay at the office. Apparently, the company doesn't like overtime, so the colleague is saying they'll stay just a little longer to finish their expense reports (経費申請) without being noticed.

経費申請少しやっちゃいます。残ったとばれない程度に。
I'll do some expense reports - just enough that they won't notice I stayed late.

